# I need an algorithm to indentify created shapes on the ground and fill them(change the colors of the blocks within)

Tags: algorithm, unity-game-engine, game-development

I am building a game where **8 players** are spawned in an arena and each **has their own color** and they are suppose to roam around the arena(the blocks they walk on change to the player's color) with the purpose to fill as much of the arena's ground with their color.

When they create a shape they inside of the shape is also **supposed to change to their color** but I can't think of a way to actually implement this so I would really appreciate some help.

I broke down the process of implementing this into 2 steps:

1. Identify when a shape is created
2. Find all the blocks that are inside the perimeter of that shape an fill them

An example for shape that I would like to fill(The blue blocks are supposed to be the perimeter of the shape

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by `shape`?  A line would be a shape, drawing of `L` `M` letters would be a shape too. If you mean `closed polygon` or `closed paths` take a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33335279/what-would-be-the-most-efficient-way-to-detect-all-closed-paths-in-a-collection

Comment: You've actually stumbled across an old problem in computer graphics :) . Check out _[Point in polygon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point_in_polygon)_ used in _hit test_ or _flood-filling_.   Essentially in your case you would for each cell, draw an imaginary line from the center of the cell to the "left", counting the number of crossings.  If it's an "odd" number, the cell is inside the boundary and therefore subject to be filled in.  Happy Unity'ing :)